# Recurring Sports Injury

Tags: strength, injury-prevention

I am an athlete for professional football club. However, I feel like I'm with the physio more than the grass. When I get over my hamstring strain, I don't want to sit on the bench again. I want to keep myself in peak condition to avoid injuries. I get through a lot of growth spurts and I have been advised to do more stretching so my muscles can adapt easier. I want to get stronger in the gym from head to toe. What are the key things I need to do to make me stronger and avoid injury? Please help. I want my career to last a lot longer, so, please come up with some goods ideas.

Comment: Did you evr think about something like yoga to prepare and strengthen  your ligaments and joints? Its in demanding sports like e.g. pro wrestling  in comming. If you feel normal yoga is to feminin or whatsover for you (in my eyes thats just ignorance of many peaopel) look at something like DDP Yoga. A former pro wrestler now Yoga trainer.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that since you are part of a professional team, you have access to a strength and conditioning coach.  If that’s not the case, I would suggest you seek one out to improve your overall conditioning and fitness.  Secondly, I would seriously think about looking into [sport specific training](http://breakingmuscle.com/strength-conditioning/sport-specific-training-what-specifically-do-you-mean-by-that).  By that I mean, changing your weight room training to include movements that closely resemble what you would be doing on the “grass”.  For example, I am a competitive rower.  My training targets the muscle groups that are engaged when I row.  This typically involves legs, back, and arms.  Rowing is mostly a pushing movement, so, training legs using exercises to increase my ability to “drive” is a goal.  Secondarily, the back is involved while driving with the legs because it draws the oar through the water.  So, I include exercises on a seated row machine, etc.

Lastly, make sure you include stretching and other modalities to help in the recovery process.  This would include making sure you get proper nutrition and enough rest to handle the demands of the “grass”.